# Spring Boot endpoint with suspend function

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, maven, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with Spring Boot, Kotlin, Reactor (Spring Webflux) and Maven. I know Maven can cause some issues with Kotlin dependencies sometimes, I think it's the case.

One of my controller's endpoints need to call a suspend function, so it needs to be suspend too.
When I use a suspend function in this context I get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt`

I heard that you can add the dependencies `kotlinx-coroutines-core` and `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` to make it work in Spring, but I'm not completely sure, I added those and it still doesn't work.

I know sometimes Kotlin dependencies don't work with Maven and there's a "jvm" version of Kotlin dependencies that should work, `kotlinx-coroutines-core` has a jvm version, but `kotlinx-coroutines-reactor` don't.

If anyone can bring me some clarity with any of my confusions I would be grateful.

Comment: have you found out how to solve this?

Comment: A code example would help clarify the problem. The error mention `Mono`, but you say you want to use top-level suspend function. To my knowledge these are not used together; [here is how reactive translates to coroutines](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.25/reference/html/languages.html#how-reactive-translates-to-coroutines).